# Scanning multiple inputs and outputting based on the amount true/false - in C

Tags: c, if-statement, nested, scanf

I have an assignment that is supposed to ask the user a few questions about temperature in regards to a plane launch.

EX:

- What is the average temperature?
- Lowest temperature in the past day?
- Is it raining?

Now the program is suppose to take the input and base it on a few conditions

- temperature must be 42 degrees
- temperature couldn't have dropped below 32
- Can't be raining

So I got the output that gives 'the okay' for the plane launch by nesting some 'if statements', that's all good. The problem is that, depending on the number of incorrect statements, it'll output something different.

EX:

If the only issue is that the temperature is below 32 degrees, it'll output:

"**The plane is not launching because the temperature has dropped below 32 degrees in the past day**"

If the temperature dropped below 32 degrees AND it's raining, the program will spit out

"**The plane is not launching because:**

**The temperature is below 32 degrees**

**it's raining**"

I know that I can make a whole bunch of if statements for each situation but that'll just make my code massive and confusing. Surely there must be a simpler way to set it up in which 'there are 2 statements false, so print this depending on which 2'. Should I make a switch statement?

The last class I took I separated all of the work into functions and then just called down each one into the main when needed. In this course, we have to do all of the work in the main function and it is kinda confusing because I began learning a different way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have three true/false conditions, for a total of eight possible outcomes. So all you need is an array of eight strings, and code to combine the three answers into a 3 bit number.

Comment: @user3386109 We haven't gone over arrays yet in this course so I assume we aren't allowed to use them. We've done if/else statements, switch statements, loops and nothing beyond that

Comment: I'd get the three inputs.  Then I'd evaluate: `if (not too cold and never froze and not raining) { print "All Systems Go" else { print "The plane is not launching because "; pad = ""; if (too cold) { print /*pad,*/ "it is too cold"; pad " and"; } if (it froze) { print pad, "it froze last night"; pad = " and"; } if (it is raining) { print pad, "it is raining"; /* pad = " and"; */ } putchar('\n');`.  Just four tests.  The `pad` allows you to build up the list of reasons cumulatively.

Answer (score 1):

The [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C) combined with format strings is a handy way to solve this problem.

The ternary operator allows you to conditionally-assign a value based on some boolean expression, and format strings let you inject other strings into your printfs, even empty strings:

```
char *cond1 = temperature_is_low ? "the temperature is low" : "";
char *cond2 = is_raining ? "it's raining" : "";
char *sep = (temperature_is_low && is_raining) ? " and " : "";
printf("The plane will not launch because %s%s%s.\n", cond1, sep, cond2);
```

If you can't use ternary operators or format strings, you could do the same thing by separating the print over multiple lines:

```
printf("The plane will not launch because ");
if (temperature_is_low)
    printf("the temperature is low");
if (temperature_is_low && is_raining)
    printf(" and ");
if (is_raining)
    printf("it's raining");
printf(".\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
#define avgTmpErrMsg "the temperature is below 42 degrees"
#define lowTmpErrMsg "the temperature has dropped below 32 degrees in the past day"
#define rainingErrMsg "it's raining"


short state = (avgTmp < 42) + ((lowTmp < 32)<<1) + ((raining)<<2); // store the state in one simple variable
short nErr = (avgTmp < 42) + (lowTmp < 32) + (raining); // number of error
switch(nErr){
   case 0: // no error
      printf("could launch\n");
      break;
   case 1: // one error
      printf("The plane is not launching because %s\n", msg(state,1));
      break;
   case 2: // 2 errors
      printf("The plane is not launching because:\n%s\n%s\n",msg(state,1),msg(state,2));
      break;
   case 3: // 3 errors
      printf("The plane is not launching because:\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",msg(state,1),msg(state,2),msg(state,3));
      break;
}



char* msg(short err,short n) {
    /* print the nth error stored in err */
    return ((err&1 && (!(--n)))? avgTmpErrMsg : ((err&2 && (!(--n)))? lowTmpErrMsg : rainingErrMsg));
}
```